# Proof degenerating discrete probability.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

[image: Proof:]

I'm finding the yellow square confusing in this proof, why $X=E[X]$? I mean indirectly it makes sense with the $c=\mu$, but how do they directly equate?

Comment: If $X=c$ is a constant (at least probabilistically) then the expected value of $X$ is the only value $X$ can attain, that is $E[X]=c$

Comment: The expression $X=\mathbb EX$ is not quite sound. The LHS is a random variable (hence a function $\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R$) and the RHS is an element of $\mathbb R$. In that sense your confusion is justified. The expression $X=c$ must red as: $P(\{X=c\})=1$, or in a lot of cases even stronger: $X(\omega)=c$ for each $\omega\in\Omega$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\exists c \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $P(X = c) = 1$, then $E[X] = E[c] = c$.

I think the order is quite confusing. I think better is

$$X = c = E[X] := \mu,$$

which is to say: $X$ is a constant $c$ and hence is equal to its expected value which we denote $\mu$